# REST .net login service

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a login service in REST using WCF or Web API.

Using an MVC project template it generates me a service like:

```
getValues()
getValue(int)
deleteValue(int)
updateValue(int,post)
```

However, I want a service like `checkLogin(username, password)` that returns `true` or `false`. The current template only allows me to add id `api/values/5`, I cannot convert it to a query string `api/values/user=123&pass=123` because it reports that the path contains `&` which is unsecure. Please Help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as follows: (WCF VS-Project)

```
Public Function Login(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String) As String Implements IBasicService.Login
        If user Is Nothing Or pass Is Nothing Then
            Return "No"
        End If
        Dim con = cnc.grpconection
        Dim com = con.CreateCommand()
        com.CommandText = "select * from Emp where UserName = @usr AND password = @pass"
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr", user)
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass)
        con.Open()
        Dim reader = com.ExecuteReader()
        Try
            reader.Read()
            If reader.HasRows Then
                Return "Yes"
            End If
            Return "No"
        Finally
            reader.Close()
            com.Dispose()
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Function
```

With interface function

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebInvoke(Method:="GET", ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate:="login?user={user}&pass={pass}")>
Function Login(ByVal user As String, ByVal pass As String) As String
```

Thanks for this excellent article www.topwcftutorials.net/2013/09/simple-steps-for-restful-service.html